# shortest way to automatic update angular cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, cordova

i have my application built around angularjs@1 using gulp, my final output is 2 javascript files and 2 css files.

this final index.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
        <title>Momen</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body layout="row" ng-include="'common/body.html'" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
    </body>
</html>
```

my question is sometimes i need to push a small update chaning couple lines in app.js

**note that i use templateCache so all my html files are also inside my app.js**

what is the best way to update app.js on the fly without resubmitting app to apple ?

Comment: are apple politics on apps allow to include external resources? if yes - just include it, if no - it's not possible (virus protection or something like that which prevent unchecked external resources inclusion?)

Comment: I've been thinking about doing the same. Maybe inject app.js dynamically from a server?

Comment: @carlosdubusm and then apple says you trying to include not checked external js file that can harm user and bans you forever from store or something like that

Comment: @llamerr that's a good point

Comment: @llamerr since there is couple update on fly solutions out there like ionic deploy etc. i think apple is fine with it .. or else how they getaway with it :o ?

Comment: that's a good idea - you can check how they doing it